# Find if a specific string exists after a specific string on the following line

Tags: python, linux

I'm creating a script in which i'm looking for a specific string in a file, then print the next 5 following lines, However, the initial string could be found in other areas of the file and are unnecessary, So i'm trying to add an additional check to see if **the next line** contains a specific string then print the content if not, don't print it:

```
f = open(i, 'r')
msg = 'somestring'
for line in f:
    if msg in line: # I would like to add a check if a specific (**somestring following 
                     # the msg on the next line**) exists on the next line,  string here
        for string in range(5):
            print line + ''.join(islice(f, 5))
```

Comment: Could you share an example file and what your desired output would be?

Comment: for example I'm looking the following strings

        Description = "" # on the first line
 ErrorCode = x ;  # on the second line

Comment: Did my answer not work for you?

Comment: Thanks smarx! However it didn't work, Here are more details, the specific strings i'm looking for: 

        Description = "Something";
 ErrorCode  0;
 EstimatedInstallTime = 30;
 EvaluationState = 1;

However, If i make the above code as: msg = 'Description = " '
it prints all lines which include Description, without the = sign and " as well.
I want it to only print the Descriptions + 5 next line if the next line that follows contains: Errorcode

Comment: It would help a lot if you would provide actual sample input and output. To clarify, are you using the code from my answer or not?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the sort of data you've indicated.

Comment: Thank you sooo MUCH!!  the updated code worked! 

I have a question for you though on a different logic, 
Wouldn't this work ? 

 if (first_string in line and if second_string in next(f)):
do somtheing ?

Comment: The problem with that code is that it would consume the second line. (Give it a try to see!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First attempt:

```
from itertools import islice

first_string = 'Description = "'
second_string = 'ErrorCode'

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if first_string in line:
            next_line = next(f)
            if second_string in next_line:
                print(next_line + ''.join(islice(f, 4)))
```

test.txt:

```
Description = "Something"
FalseAlarm = true

Description = "Something"
ErrorCode 0
EstimatedInstallTime = 30
EvaluationState = 1
Something = Else
More = Here
```

Output:

```
ErrorCode 0
EstimatedInstallTime = 30
EvaluationState = 1
Something = Else
More = Here
```